# creating a generic remapping function

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

I have a class full of different lists, and I want an easy way of remapping their values.
So I tried to create a generic remap method like this

```
private List<Row> list = new ArrayList<>();

@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Data
private class Row {
    private String data;
}
public <T> void reMap(Class<T> builderClass, Function<T, T> rowMapper) {
    if(builderClass.equals(Row.class)) {
        list = list.stream().map(Row::toBuilder).map(rowMapper).map(Row::build).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

but it complains on the `rowMapper` saying

```
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that RowBuilder conforms to T
```

It have a hard time understanding why that is, and if there is a decent way around it?

Comment: Why do you need a generic function if you only do anything for one specific class?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `builderClass` parameter?

Comment: Basically because I don't want to clutter my class with a `reMap` function for every single list. My example is really shortened and in reallity I have almost 20 lists and it would be really nice to avoid having 20 `reMap` functions that are virtually the same

Comment: @Sweeper my thought was to be able to bind T to an actuall type at runtime. If I remember correctly (I probably don't) the java compiler would clean away all generic types if it isn't bound to something like for example a class

Comment: Note: `Function<T, T>` could be rewritten to `UnaryOperator<T>`.

Comment: @MCEmperor it could, but that is a more specific type. You can use a UO as an F, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

> It have a hard time understanding why that is, and if there is a decent way around it?

The simple answer is: because you (are able to) know more than the compiler.

You are checking that `builderClass` is `Row`. In the case that it is, the compiler doesn't "remember" that: that is, you have to keep on telling the compiler that it is, e.g. by casting.

But then, the compiler doesn't know anything about the relationship between the `Row` and `RowBuilder` classes. In terms of the type system, there is no relationship: they are just two classes.

So, is there a decent way around this? No, not really. If possible, try not to do this with generics.